# How to create a button to sort date in ascending and descending?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

[Activation Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mamZa.jpg)
Hi, I am having trouble with arranging my Date from ascending to descending and vice versa. So I have a column called Activation Date, and I want it to be able to arrange the column when the table head "Activation Date" is clicked. I am using data from my database.

```
  echo "<th><a href='sortDate.php?member={$brokerName}&memberid={$brokerID}&sort=asc' class='btn btn-sm' role='button'>Activation Date</a></th>"
```

The above is the code for the Activation Date. Basically I put the link to return user back to the same page, with the intend of displaying the column either in descending or ascending order.

For the sortDate.php, I used the select statement from my database to order the column to ASC and DESC depending on the value of the page. However, when I try it, it just keeps returning me to the same page with no changes.

```
if ($sort == 'asc') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM applicantdetails WHERE EmployeeID={$brokerID} ORDER BY ActivationDate DESC";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
header("Location: brokerDetailTest.php?member={$brokerName}&memberid={$brokerID}"); } else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM applicantdetails WHERE EmployeeID={$brokerID} ORDER BY ActivationDate ASC";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
header("Location: brokerDetailTest.php?member={$brokerName}&memberid={$brokerID}");}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the $_GET array to "get" the information from the url. You used sort='asc' in your url. SO use something like this. I think for the sorting REVERSED ASC AND DESC in your query

```
    $sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : null ;

    //for the ASC part
    if ($sort == 'asc') 
    {
    }
    //DESC part
    else{

    }
```

Comment: Oops thank you for your reply, I realized I didn't show that part in the php. 
I used something similar like this:
$sort = $_GET["sort"];
echo $sort;
Are both of these $_GET method the same?
I did the if and else part on the 2nd code section of the code. I just made it into one line, because stack overflow didn't recognize it as a single code.

Comment: yes they are the same! you need also to add  the isset part to not get errors if the $_GET['sort'] is empty.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean thank you! I am still having trouble displaying it.

Comment: Ok i see. There is a problem with your link format of Activation Button. it should be like <a href=sort.php?sort="ASC">Activation Asc</a> and other button <a href=sort.php?sort="DES">Activation Des</a>. Remove all the user ID stuff. REMOVE them. It will be simpler and efficient.

Comment: I added the member stuff so that I can return details specific to a client. I do have another select statement from another side to display the data for the Activation Date and the Status. I think it may be because of that.